# Gstreamer example project is not working. (/subprojects/gst-rtsp-server/examples/test-onvif-server)

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, onvif

I was trying to run the gstreamer example project from the /subprojects/gst-rtsp-server/examples/test-onvif-server.

```
$ ./subprojects/gst-rtsp-server/examples/test-onvif-server ~/Downloads/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4
```

And I got this output in the terminal. "`stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test`".

Then I opened the link in the Totem video player. but it showed the following prints in the terminal.

```
stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
0:00:05.681326198  6322 0x560ab751ccc0 ERROR           onvif-server test-onvif-server.c:496:create_replay_bin: Could not create element filesrc

(test-onvif-server:6322): GStreamer-RTSP-Server-CRITICAL **: 10:41:53.436: could not create element
0:00:05.681420723  6322 0x560ab751ccc0 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:1096:find_media: client 0x560ab7530100: can't create media
0:00:05.681458700  6322 0x560ab751ccc0 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:3412:handle_describe_request: client 0x560ab7530100: no media
```

What causing this issue? any help would be appreciated.

OS - UBUNTU 22.04.03 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arose from the incorrect configuration of environment variables, resulting in GStreamer not functioning as intended.

To resolve this issue, please execute either `meson devenv -C <builddir>` or `./gst-env.py`. These commands will correctly set up the environment variables necessary for GStreamer to operate effectively.